# How to sync some collections between two MongoDB databases?

Tags: mongodb

I'm looking for some ways to sync some collections between two MongoDB databases, for instance sync some collections from a local db to a production db. If I use `mongodump` and `mongorestore` only new documents will be added to the remote DB, the existing ones won't be updated since `mongorestore` doesn't perform updates. The alternative would be to delete and recreate the collection every time using the `mongodump` output, but I want to avoid (if possible) this approach. So is it possible to synchronize a collection between two MongoDB Databases without having to recreate the collection every time?

Comment: I've had to do something similar to this and I ended up writing an application to manually copy all of the items out of database A to database B.  If you use the upsert functionality of your chosen driver, you will be able to get away without dropping the target database first.

Comment: In further searches I've seen the `mongoimport` comand has the upsert argument. Since I don't need to sync the entire database but just some collections I may need to use this. Would be good or there are some flaws using this command?

Answer (score 1):

I just finished tool diffmongo https://github.com/datacoon/diffmongo that generates list of differences between MongoDb tables and allows to sync collections without drop/restore.
But it still could be slower, since it deletes, appends and updates changes for each deleted, added and updated record.

Answer (score 0):

there is a mongo-sync config on the config.yml file. There is a similar question here: [How to perform one-time DB sync to another DB in MongoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12419181/how-to-perform-one-time-db-sync-to-another-db-in-mongodb)

See if this is helpful to you.

Comment: That solution appears to drop the target database before writing the new data.

Comment: I've seen that project, but sadly it doesn't fit my case. First because it drops the target database before restore, second because it doesn't allow the restore of some collections (and I've seen [this issue](https://github.com/sheharyarn/mongo-sync/issues/5) where the author explains why he won't add such feature)